# Surface integral on sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Is there a direct way to calculate the surface integral of the gradient of some smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ over the sphere $S^2$ without knowing $f$? 
$$
\int\int_{S^2}grad(f) \eta\,dS=?
$$
I mean, is this integral independent of the function $f$?

Comment: In general, NO. However, if $f$ is a [harmonic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) inside the interior of $S^2$ (i.e $\nabla^2 f = 0$ there), then you can use [divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) to conclude the surface integral vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=k|x|$, then the gradient is a $k$-multiple of the outwards normal and $\int\nabla f\cdot \eta=4k \pi^2$ which can be any real number.

However, the result doesn't change if you add to $\nabla f$ any divergence-free vector field (use Stokes).